# List of objects implementing an interface and interface extension

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, instanceof

If I have an interface A and an interface B that extends A.
In a List of A how can I recognise the objects that implement B and so call the methodB of interface B on them?

```
public interface A{
 void methodA();
}

public interface B extends A{
 void methodB();
}

public class CA implements A{
 public void methodA(){}
}

public class CB implements B{
 public void methodA(){}
 public void methodB(){}
}

public static void main(String [] args){
 List<A> l = new ArrayList<>();
 l.add(new CA());
 l.add(new CB());
}
```

Should I use instanceof or there are better solution using polymorphism?

**Edit:**
I’am trying to develop a hierarchy to execute some commands for a simple game. The basic commands like Move and MoveRandom implements the interface  Command. Now I want to add a repeat command and to manage the loop I have extended the Command interface with a LoopCommand interface(to respect the interface segregation principle). So when I have the List of Commands I need to know if the  command is a LoopCommand and in this case call the anotherIteraction() method to know if stay on the command or go to the next command. For this reason I have done the initial question. There are better hierarchy or solution to manage the loop commands?

```
public interface Command{
 void execute();
}

public interface LoopCommand extends Command{
 public boolean anotherIteraction();
}

public class Move implements Command{
 public void execute(){}
}

public class Repeat implements LoopCommand{
 private List<Command> body;
 private repetition;
 
 boolean anotherIteraction(){
 /*logics to determinate if there are other commands to execute*/
 }

 public void execute(){/*execute 1 command from the list body*/}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
 List<Command> l = new ArrayList<>();
 l.add(new Move());
 l.add(new Repeat());
 int i=0;
 while(i<l.size()){
  l.get(i).execute();
  if(l.get(i) instance of LoopCommand c){
   if(!c.anotherIteraction)
     i++;
  } else 
      i++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Polymorphism would work only if the base interface contained all the methods of the subinterfaces, with appropriate default behaviors. You'd still need to use instanceof (or reflection) however unless all the default behaviors were no-ops.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you need control to return to your main execution loop between each command that a `LoopCommand` executes? That is, you can move the loop to the body of `Repeat.execute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `instanceof`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface A {
    void methodA();
}

interface B extends A {
    void methodB();
}

class CA implements A {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("CA's implementation of interface A");
    }
}

class CB implements B {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("CB's implementation of interface A");

    }

    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("CB's implementation of interface B");
    }
}

public class InstanceOfDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new CA());
        list.add(new CB());

        for (A obj : list) {

            if (obj instanceof B ob) {
                ob.methodB();
            } else {
                obj.methodA();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
CA's implementation of interface A
CB's implementation of interface B
```

Comment: Thank you. I red your comment about the XY problem, I didn't know this problem before,  but I  think you are right so I have edited the question. Could you help me?

Comment: It's difficult to understand how this works with the supplied description.  But maybe you could just store the commands in a `List<String>` like "move" and "repeat" and  then use a `switch(command)` block  to chose the command and take the appropriate action.  And you can have nested switch blocks if required.